# Reducing CPU Usage while using reading a file

Tags: python

This is the idea, behind my project, playing around with the hashlib modules, when user enters a hash, all uppercase lower case combination are tried to find if a match is found, everything is fine, works great, the only problem Is with the CPU usage, which shoots upto 50%-60%.. Anyhow, is there a way to decrease the cpu usage?

OS: Windows

Part Of The Code:

```
def md5(file, torev):
    with open(file) as f:
        for i in f:
            i = i.replace("\n", "")
            s = map(''.join, itertools.product(*zip(i.upper(), i.lower())))
            for k in s:
                rev = hashlib.md5(k).hexdigest()
                if rev == torev:
                   print "[+] Hash Value Found"
                   print "[+] Value: "+k
                   break
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using `imap` and `izip` then

Comment: What's the point? Hash calculation is obviously CPU bound. Your point is?

Comment: @jamylak: But those won't actually reduce CPU usage appreciably, only memory usage.

Comment: what has imap, izip to do here?

Comment: @Maulwurfn yes i knw, its bound, just a discussion, like, if any method is there, to reduce it unknown to me.. i love the Py Geeks Here :)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams just posted as comment since it wasn't the answer. They will be more memory efficient as `map` and `zip` return a `list` while `izip` and `imap` are generators and you will only be running through the combos once instead of twice

Comment: @jamylak ok i wil try using imap and see if i get any difference :)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to reduce CPU usage in this instance is to move the hash calculation off the CPU, perhaps onto a GPU with OpenCV/OpenCL.